# Access VBA reselect items in List Box

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I'm working on a DB where the users have to select items from multiple list boxes, at the end of the all of this, the form closes and opens a new form. All of that works great.

My issue is that when the user goes back to the original form, I want it to load in with their list box items already highlighted. Sort of a "here is where you left off" kind of thing.

I have code that works, but it's somewhat limited:

```
If InStr(me.Backup_Chain, "Apple") > 0 then
   Me.List_Type.Selected(0) = true
End if
If InStr(me.Backup_Chain, "Grapes") > 0 then
   Me.List_Type.Selected(1) = true
End if
```

"List_Type" is just a textbox that I populate with the users previous selection. So if they selected Apples and Grapes it reads: 'Apples','Grapes'

This works pretty well, but it's not dynamic. So if I add "Bananas" to the list, Bananas because item number 1 in the list, and thus screws up all of my other references.

So, my question is 2 parts:

1. Is there an easier way or reselecting the list box items?
2. If not, is there a way to make the Selected(#) dynamic? i.e. to tell that "Grapes" is in location 1 vs 2.

Thanks everyone!

Edit: In addition to this, I have a run a query to filter one of the list boxes down to a subgroup of clients (based on the other list box selections). Which means I need to refresh the page. So I can't get by with just hiding the form.

Comment: Just leave the first form open and hide it instead of closing it. Then show it again. The listbox entries will stay selected. (`Me.Visible = False` and `Forms!theForm.Visible = True`.

Comment: Well that's good to know! That will work for part of it but not the whole thing. 

I have a segment where the person can select from a list of customers, but I want that list to optionally filter down based on their selections, which means I need to refresh the page. Unless there is a fun trick for that too!

Comment: Another possibility is to add the selected items to a [Collection](http://www.functionx.com/vbaccess2010/topics/collection.htm) and to use this information later to reselect the items.